# jQuery - shorthand way of writing this

Tags: jquery, performance

I have the below jQuery script that I need some help with shortening.
This script works but is obviously not written the best that it can be.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

var expenses = jQuery( "#expenses tbody tr" ).length;
var income = jQuery( "#income tbody tr" ).length;
var bills = jQuery( "#bills tbody tr" ).length;

jQuery( ".income .badge" ).text( income );
jQuery( ".expenses .badge" ).text( expenses );
jQuery( ".bills .badge" ).text( bills );

});
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What about it bothers you?

Comment: You can use `$(".classname")` instead of `jQuery(".classname")`

Comment: Is there no shorthand way of writing this?

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Haha :). OP: you could avoid those variables.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question - but it may be better suited to the code review site...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.each(['income', 'expenses', 'bills'], function(index, cat) {
        $('.'+cat+' .badge').text($('#'+cat+' tbody tr').length);
    });
});
```

...is probably about as succinct as you can make this, but at the arguable expense of readability.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of correcting the use of the arguments in the callback (`$.each` gives them to you in a weird order).

Comment: Ah yes, I always forget jQ gives you index before value (the reverse of how PHP more sensibly does it). Thanks.

Comment: Native forEach implementations and underscorejs give value as first argument too. Consistency to the max for jQ

Comment: Yeah - I avoided native `forEach` just for older browser purposes.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you *can* do it like this, but I'm not sure it buys you much:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $( ".income .badge" ).text( $( "#income tbody tr" ).length );
    $( ".expenses .badge" ).text( $( "#expenses tbody tr" ).length );
    $( ".bills .badge" ).text( $( "#bills tbody tr" ).length );
});
```

Notes:

- Even in `noConflict` mode, if you're using the `ready` callback, the first argument to it is the `jQuery` function. So you can accept that argument using the name `$` and use that within the `ready` callback.
- `jQuery(function($) { ... })` is functionally identical to `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });` (e.g., it's a shortcut).
- You don't have to save the values to local variables before you use them.

But note that #2 might make it more awkward to debug this if you needed to. You can also [go a bit further](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550726/157247) as Utkanos points out in his answer.

Separately: You only need `ready` if you don't control where your script tags go. If you do, just put your script tag at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and you can ditch `ready`. You still probably want the wrapper function, though:

```
(function($) {
    $( ".income .badge" ).text( $( "#income tbody tr" ).length );
    $( ".expenses .badge" ).text( $( "#expenses tbody tr" ).length );
    $( ".bills .badge" ).text( $( "#bills tbody tr" ).length );
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: +1 for this good looking/clear code.  But is it really have any performance improvement when done with local variable?

Comment: @Praveen: Performance improvement? No. There shouldn't be any performance difference between the OP's code and the first code block above at all. The second code block above may run a few milliseconds earlier than the OP's original code (a lot more than that on old IE, but...).

Comment: Thanks T.J. - does not using ready give performance improvements or just for readability/shortening?

Comment: @user537137: On modern browsers, the code will run a *little bit* sooner than when using `ready`. On older browsers, it'll run a **lot** sooner. jQuery's `ready` uses the `DOMContentLoaded` event if it exists, then falls back to various tricks if it doesn't, and ultimately uses `window`'s `load` event if it can't find anything that happens earlier. The `window` `load` event happens **very** late in the page load, after all images and other resources have been loaded. It's more than you just don't need those tricks if you control where the script goes.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function which can do the jQuery operation, then call it with the desired params

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function write(ct, badge) {
        $(badge).find(".badge").text($(ct).find(" tbody tr").length);
    }

    write('#expenses', '.expenses');
    write('#income', '.income');
    write('#bills', '.bills');
});
```

or even (since the class name and id are the same)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function write(selector) {
        $('.' + selector).find(".badge").text($('#' + selector).find(" tbody tr").length);
    }

    write('expenses');
    write('income');
    write('bills');
});
```

Comment: Seems more expensive.

Comment: @Praveen yes the additional function call adds an overhead... but in modern systems how much < 1ms may be

Comment: @Arun P Johny you missed `$('#' + ct)` to `$('#' + selector)`

Answer (score 1):

I just really like over-complicating things, so here it goes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var values = ['expenses', 'income', 'bills']; // if you need another badge you add it here
  $.each(values, function(i, val) {
    $("."+ val +" .badge" ).text($("#" + val + " tbody tr" ).length);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code would do the same thing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ['income', 'expenses', 'bills'].forEach(function(element){
        $('.' + element + ' .badge').text($('#' + element + ' tbody tr').length);
    });
});
```

but at the cost of slightly reduced readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class `foo` to `#expenses` `#income` `#bills`, you can do this:

```
$('.foo').each(function(i, el){
    var $this = $(this);
    var amount = $this.find("tbody tr").length;

    $('.' + $this.prop('id') + ' .badge').text(amount);
});
```

Note: for jQuery prior to 1.6, you must use `.attr` instead of `.prop`